# SELECT onChange event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I keep track of changes in SELECT element BEFORE user chooses an item using mouse or by pressing Enter?

One can listen to keyUp event, which allows to track user navigating through the list using keyboard. But is there more generic approach, which allows tracking list "prefinal" changes?

Comment: You can store previous values in a local javascript variable which exist until you reload the page.

Answer (score 2):

I always use `focus click` listener for this.

```
$('select').bind('focus click',function(){
//IMACHANGINGMYOPTION!!!!!!!!!!
    //var val=$(this).val();
});
```

The above should be triggered before the on change event:

```
$('select').change(function(){
//The option has been changed.
});
```

Explanation: whenever a user focuses select, we do get the value of the selected item, and we can manipulate it before the `onchange` event if triggered. The `click` listener is added in case our select is already focused, and the user *clicks* it to expand before he actually selects an option and triggers a change.

This is an example of usage, that lets us track the previous value:

http://jsfiddle.net/SUKqS/8/

Answer (score 0):

Javascript supports an 'onbeforechange' event which will probably do the trick, but I don't know how widely implemented this is across browsers?  If that is supported widely enough, store the previous value before it is changed.  Failing that, just store the original values in hidden fields or JS variables.

Comment: IE (at least 8+) does support it, I have only ever used it in a closed IE environment though so I didn't need to look at widespread implementation.

Comment: I have tested this in IE6-9, FF 11, Chrome 17, Opera 11.61, Safari 5.1.2, but there the `onbeforechange` event does **not** exist (tested `.onbeforechange = .. `, `addEventListener` and `.attachEvent`).

Answer (score 0):

there is no event that fires when moving the mouse over the select-items.

you can, as you said, track the mouse movement. But as different browsers render the lists differently, that would be a difficult task.

you can however create a selectbox yourself without using the native select

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a function like this example:-

```
function example(){
jQuery('select#service_billing_state').change(function () {
//your code here
});
}
```

and you have to call this function in onchange, onblur, onkey , onfocus...